# Web-service call from android app takes 10 mins to reflect the latest results

Tags: android, wordpress, web-services, retrofit2

Am Struggling with one of the issues of being service taking almost 10 mins to reflect the updated results. Actually, am using an API of type Get, the structure of the service is like this:

www.abc.net/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=192&page=1&per_page=2

When I try to call the service from the browser it's showing the updated information, but when I try to call the same service from my android app using retrofit it's delaying the updated response by almost 10 mins.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52868877/api-doest-give-the-updated-response-when-called-frequently-using-retrofit) is the code mentioned in my last question about the same :

```
public class ApiClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {


        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {



                Request original = chain.request();

                // Request customization: add request headers
                Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                        .cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK)
                        .addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
                        .addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");

                Request request = requestBuilder.build();

                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });

        OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();




        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ApiInterface.SERVICE_ENDPOINT)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();



        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

My API Interface

```
    public interface ApiInterface {
     String SERVICE_ENDPOINT = "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/";

       @GET("posts")
       Call<ArrayList<CategoryResponse>> fetchlatestposts(@Query("bloglist") 
                                                        int bloglist);


}
```

What can be the issue for not getting the updates response in real time, while as after 10-15 mins of pause it will give the updated results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was from the server side, WordPress has cache enabled which was causing the issue.